# JQuery Selected OR Conditions

Tags: jquery

This code looks to see if a certain value is selected, then shows a div below it accordingly. I'm wondering if I can make this an OR type of scenario. So below where I have if(selected == '2'), can it be something like if(selected == 2 or 3 etc.)?

```
$('#ftaskstatus').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    if(selected == '2'){
      $('#createnewtask').show();
    }
    else{
      $('#createnewtask').hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `||` *or* operator:

```
if (selected == "2" || selected == "3")
```

Comment: Or `$.inArray(this.value, ['2', '3', 'n']) > -1`

Comment: Or just `['2', '3', 'n'].indexOf(this.value) > -1` :)

Comment: ... if we don't want to support the -ie8 :)

Comment: I dream of not supporting IE :(